# Opening same file in two windows in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Say I have opened a file abc.cpp in one Emacs window, I want to open it in another window. If I do C-x C-f and locate the file, the cursor goes back to the original window and the file does not open in the window where I placed my cursor. If I do C-x b and identify the buffer, the cursor goes to the original window as well. I hope I can put my cursor in some other window, and open the file in that window, no matter whether the file is opened already. How can I do that? One way that seems to work is to use mouse, go to File menu and choose Open File, but that is not very nice...

Comment: If you type `C-x b` in a given window and enter the buffer name, Emacs absolutely should display that buffer in that window. It would only do otherwise if it *cannot* display the buffer in that window (quoting the documentation: "e.g. if it is a minibuffer window or strongly dedicated to another buffer"). Note that you wouldn't "open the file" a second time -- no matter how many windows are displaying a given file buffer, it's all the same buffer.

Comment: Try emacs -Q.  If that behaves as you want, then the problem is in your customizations, and you can find it by executing parts of your .emacs (or .emacs.d/init.el, and other custom files in site-lisp like site-start.el, default.el) until you narrow down where the line is that is causing this. Otherwise, you might need to look for a more standard port of Emacs to your OS, as this is not normal behavior for Emacs.

Answer (score 4):

That one is easy! The command `C-x 2` will split the window showing the buffer in two horizontally. The relevant command is `split-window-vertically`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to what @vonbrand said, you can always call `new-frame` (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `new-frame`) and the current opened file will open in a new frame (window).